# Removing the subfigures letters in LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am using LyX beamer and I need to remove the letters (e, f) in the subfigures titles attached, but keeping the captions below each figure.
[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal working example of the intermediate .tex code produced by lyx so we can see which package it uses for the subfigures.